# Will MSSQL 2012 database work on MSSQL 2008 server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have MsSQL database which is created in MSSQL 2012 SQL server.

On my local machine I have installed MSSQL 2008 SQL server.

Will the 2012 database work in MSSQL 2008?

Also,I have installed MSSQL 2012 SQL server on my local system.Do I need to install MSSQL management studio for 2012 SQL server?

Is it required for user interface?

Comment: You can recreate a copy of the database on 2008 server. What you won't be able to do is to back up the database from the 2012 server and restore it on the 2008 server. Which is what most people try to do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  ok.Do I need to download MSSQL management studio as well for user interface?

Comment: I suspect you won't get an 100% yes or no.  It would really be you have to try it.  My guess is if you can get the restore to work, the data will be fine.  If you've set up any kind of features (some kind of advanced triggering?) that isn't available in 2k8 you'll have issues

Answer (score 1):

A full database backup and restore to the new server will not work. SQL server does not allow that to a previous version.

You can however create the schema and load the data in manually through SSIS or BCP.

For SSMS you can connect to a previous version.

Comment: As replied by others, one more thing you can't restore from backup of sql server 2012 database into 2008R2. You have to take script of sql server 2012 database and then run manually on 2008R2.

Answer (score 0):

*Most of the features will work, But features specific to SQL Server 2012 may not work.*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Management Studio of SQL Server 2012 in order to browse SSMS-2012 database. You can still continue to use the  2008 R2's IDE.

Comment: Where can I enter database credentials in order to connect to database?

Comment: Use the Object Explorer to get connected. You would also get a prompt for credentials when you try to open a new Query window.

Comment: I dont have Object Explorer

Comment: You can get to the Object Explorer from View-> Object Explorer OR F8 function key

Answer (score 0):

Whether a 2012 database will work on a 2008R2 server depends.
If you are deploying to your 2008R2 server by running T-SQL scripts then it will only work if

- The database objects used in your 2012 database were available in 2008R2
- You are not using SQL2012 T-SQL enhancements in your scripts
- Your scripts do not depend on system objects or views that were introduced in SQL2012
- The local edition of SQL2008R2 is compatible with the SQL2012 edition.  For example SQL2008R2 Express will not like SQL2012 Enterprise Edition features.

Ideally you will be using the Developer Edition for your local instance as this is simply a throttled version of Enterprise Edition.

If you are trying to restore to 2008R2 from a 2012 backup then no, it won't work.

Given that SQL Management Studio is a free download why would you stick with the SQL2008R2 version?  If you have licenced SQL2012 then you are licenced for the SQL2012 version of SSMS.  Why not go the whole hog and install SSMS for SQL2017?

If you do not like SMSS then a paid for alternative might be Aquafold Data Studio.  This has the advantage of supporting many database platforms from a single IDE.

Answer (score 0):

it is not neccesarily required to have ssms 2012 . it will work as we have the sql server installed

Answer (score 0):

Just reiterating PingPongOng - a backup and restore wont work as you can't install a newer database onto an older server. You can however go the other way, so a 2008 database could migrate to a 2012 server.

As others have said, you need to create scripts.
Right click on the 2012 database, and on the menu that appears -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts and follow the wizard that appears. This will allow you to create just the schema or schema and data (if required).